# Branch exists but cannot be seen in refs/heads

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

In a bare repository (no working folder) on a BitBucket Server machine, I have two release branches:

```
# git branch --list | grep release
warning: ignoring broken ref refs/heads/integration/Team
  release/2018r1
  release/2018r2
```

But if I look in `refs/heads`, neither of these branches can be seen:

```
# ls refs/heads/release
testing
```

The `testing` branch is a branch that was deleted some time ago.

How is it possible for `release/2018r1` and `release/2018r2` to exist (and be seen by `git branch --list`) but not show up in `refs/heads`?

And why does the old `release/testing` branch show up in `refs/heads`, when it doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: Like @torek said, most refs eventually move out of refs/ and live in the packed-refs file.  p.s. Is refs/heads/release/testing a file or a directory?  What does it contain?

Comment: Ah.  `testing` is not a file at all -- it's a sub-directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference names can be either *packed* (stored in `.git/packed-refs`, which is an ordinary file) or *unpacked* (stored one per file).  A reference that exists as both unpacked and packed has its current value stored in the unpacked copy, i.e., the packed copy is not automatically deleted.

In this case the two "invisible" references are no doubt packed.  It's not clear to me what is going on with `refs/heads/release/testing`.

A future version of Git may stop storing reference names in plain-text files at all, since file names have case-folding issues on Windows and MacOS file systems.  Use `git for-each-ref` and `git update-ref` (and similar) to read and write reference values, so as to be ready for a future Git that uses an actual key-value database.